# Get Non-Database ADO Recordset Distinct records

Tags: vbscript, ado

I've created an ADO recordset (in VBScript), using `.append`.  That is, the recordset is not created by an SQL statement pulling info from a database.

Is there a SQLish way I can get records from this recordset and return it to another recordset?

E.g. `SET = adoUniqueRS = SELECT DISTINCT [FieldWithDupes] FROM [adoRSwDupes]`

---

So far, the most efficient thing I can think of is loop through a sorted `[adoRSwDupes]` on `[FieldWithDupes]` and add a new record to `[adoUniqueRS]` when `[FieldWithDupes]` changes values.

Any better ideas?

Comment: I suggest you to use a dictionary, like described [here](http://www.knowledgeinbox.com/articles/vbscript/removing-duplicate-values-from-a-list-of-values/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know a way to run a query against a disconnected recordset, sorry.

In the ideas area, once the recordset is sorted, instead of iterating over the complete recordset, you can filter it. The idea is:

```
While recordset has records 
    Get first record data
    Filter the recordset to data > retrieved data
```

That way, after aplying the filter, the current record will be the first in the next set of data. Repeat until no data left.

Comment: I like this idea and I think I'll use it in the future.  After thinking about the efficiency of iterating the entire RS vs. this method, I think your method would be more efficient for where the duplicate values are a large percentage of the set.  I think iterating  the whole set is more efficient when there's like two of each value.

I couldn't prove one way or another with my particular data, but it's a good idea for sure! Thanks.